# Step-by-step description of the preparations, gear, apps, settings, ... needed to take image of a plane before the moon

Tags: calculations, moon, tutorial, airplanes

I recently saw the following photograph [on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/epixelaerospace/posts/pfbid036yBPseUhVQnEa6BeuEWEnhJKFKWAQU2ZVTxtiF6iqr6qEMZCAoNjBf2uYvTtzvaBl) by [ePixel Aerospace](https://www.facebook.com/epixelaerospace):

[image]

with the following caption:

> Mission accomplished!
>
> Just about a year ago, I was commissioned to
> capture a special Qantas/Lunar photo by a keen Qantas F/O.
> After a number of attempts being aborted due to La Niña weather conditions in recent times, an opportunity presented itself on Friday morning.
> A difficult shot, given the departure time was a little before Sunrise.
> The Sun was dimly glowing on the fuselage as the F/O who was driving,
> began a left turn and fortunately for me with my calculations, lined
> up perfectly to cross the centreline of a very bright 2022 'Buck'
> Super Moon against a deep blue dawn sky. One of the most challenging
> aviation photos I have captured to date!
>
> Qantas Boeing 737-838 Reg.
> VH-VYH 'Queanbeyan' crosses the Waning Gibbous Moon 98.0%. Brisbane to
> Melbourne, Australia as flight QF605.
>
> Speed 366 km/h Altitude 1,739 ft
> Track 132° Image Date 15 July 2022 Canon EOS R3, Canon EF 400mm f/2.8
> L IS III USM Lens +2.0x III
>
> Qantas Australian Aviation World of
> Aviation Canon Australia
>
> #qantas #qantasairways #boeing #BoeingLovers #boeing737 #b737 #Queanbeyan #moon #buckmoon #supermoon #aviationphotography #planespotting #avporn #aviationporn #planeporn #aviationgeek #planegeek #avgeek #airplanelovers #airplane #aviation #planespotter #CanonR3 #R3 #mirrorless
> #canonmirrorless

I am looking for a tutorial/guide/step-by-step description of the preparations, gear, apps, settings, ... needed to take such a shot.

From the description I can already gather that the following:

- the photographer used a 400mm lens with a 2.0x extender
- the photographer used a high shutter speed to take several pictures in quick succession for the fraction of a second it took for the plane to pass the moon
- the shot was planned on the date of a Super Moon
- the photographer probably used an app like [PhotPills](https://www.photopills.com/) to calculate the position of the moon
- It is not entirely clear from the text if the plane was flying it's normal path or if there was some coordination between the photographer and the First Officer to alter the flight path

Thanks!

Comment: The only step is more work than seems reasonable. A big pile of money would help. Or just use photoshop.

Comment: Highly unlikely that the FO was able to alter the course of the flight if it was a regularly scheduled Quantas flight. There are all sorts of standard departures that are used at larger airports like Brisbane, and if the airspace is busy, odds are good that ATC will say "no".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the author did was wait a few miles down an airport runway. How far down? Well, you go to a site like [FlightRadar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/) (there is also a mobile app), and look at planes taking off (if possible the same model as your target, but similar planes have similar climb rates). Watching jets taking off from La Guardia show that they reach 1700ft (518m) (altitude of the plane in the picture) around 3km after the end of the run way. This is also coincidentally where they start turning to head towards their destination. This is an important information for your photo, because the plane will bank to the inside and so make it look like it was shot from above, this is why the left turn is important in your example shot because a picture with the plane belly wouldn't have been so great.

How far from the axis so you want to be? In the picture the plane is roughly 3 times the size of the moon, so 1.5°. A 737-3xx is 33m long, so the distance from the camera is

```
D = (33/2)/tan(1.5°/2) = 1260m
```

But this is the distance between the camera and the plane, so the distance on the ground from the runway axis is

```
G = √(1260²-518²) = 1149m
```

And at that point you will be aiming your camera with an angle above the horizon:

```
ɑ = arcsin(518/1260) = 24°
```

... which is also where the moon should be.

So now you want the moon to have an altitude of 24° above the horizon, with an azimuth roughly perpendicular to the runway, a bit before sunset... That will depend a lot on the airport, and may not be possible in some.  Consult your planetarium application for the details.

Comment: Or a bit shortly after sunrise, rather than before sunset. I find that most large airports tend to have more planes taking off around sunrise than around sunset. Most have more planes landing in the evening.